# How to get combination of value from single column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get distinct possible combination value from single column in BigQuery.

Suppose i have this table:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|   date   |type  |payment |customer_no|status|
+---------------------------------------------+
|2019-01-02|Shirt |Cashless|        101|Cancel|
|2019-01-02|Jeans |Cashless|        133|OK    |
|2019-01-02|Jeans |Cash    |        102|OK    |
|2019-01-02|Cap   |Cash    |        144|OK    |
|2019-01-02|Shirt |Cash    |        132|OK    |
|2019-01-01|Jeans |Cash    |        111|Cancel|
|2019-01-01|Cap   |Cash    |        141|OK    |
|2019-01-01|Shirt |Cash    |        101|OK    |
|2019-01-01|Jeans |Cash    |        105|OK    |
```

- I wanna take with rules:

  - Only status = 'OK'
  - No repetition in combination like **Shirt, Jeans** and **Jeans, Shirt** is unacceptable
  - Group for each payment and its combination **(Cash, Cassless, Cash&Cashless)**

With this code:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT  date,
        type,
        COUNT(customer_no) as total_customer_per_order_type,
        order_payment
FROM `blabla.order`
WHERE status = 'OK'
GROUP BY date, type , payment
ORDER BY date DESC, payment ASC
```

i just got total customer for single type

How to get table something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEtEQ.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your expected output.  In any case, you should definitely include that directly in your question.  Do not paste links.

Comment: and please explain the logic of getting output  - just asking for something like something - usually does not work!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i'm sorry, but i can't post an image yet

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant i myself lack on logic within this output, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and answers just the exact question in the title of your post which is:

> How to get combination of value from single column?

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test(a ARRAY<INT64>) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  var combine = function(a) {
    var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
      if (n == 0) {
        if (got.length > 0) {
          all[all.length] = got;
        } return;
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
      } return;
    }
    var all = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
      fn(i, a, [], all);
    }
    all.push(a);
    return all;
  } 
  return combine(a)
''';
WITH types AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT type, CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY type) AS STRING) type_num
  FROM `project.dataset.order`
  WHERE status = 'OK'
)
SELECT items, STRING_AGG(type ORDER BY type_num) types
FROM UNNEST(test(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM types)))) AS items, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(items)) AS pos
JOIN types ON pos = type_num
GROUP BY items
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your questions as in below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test(a ARRAY<INT64>) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  var combine = function(a) {
    var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
      if (n == 0) {
        if (got.length > 0) {
          all[all.length] = got;
        } return;
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
      } return;
    }
    var all = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
      fn(i, a, [], all);
    }
    all.push(a);
    return all;
  } 
  return combine(a)
''';
WITH `project.dataset.order` AS (
  SELECT '2019-01-02' dt, 'Shirt' type, 'Cashless' payment, 101 customer_no, 'Cancel' status UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-02', 'Jeans', 'Cashless', 133, 'OK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-02', 'Jeans', 'Cash', 102, 'OK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-02', 'Cap', 'Cash', 144, 'OK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-02', 'Shirt', 'Cash', 132, 'OK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-01', 'Jeans', 'Cash', 111, 'Cancel' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-01', 'Cap', 'Cash', 141, 'OK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-01', 'Shirt', 'Cash', 101, 'OK' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-01', 'Jeans', 'Cash', 105, 'OK' 
), types AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT type, CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY type) AS STRING) type_num
  FROM `project.dataset.order`
  WHERE status = 'OK'
)
SELECT items, STRING_AGG(type ORDER BY type_num) types
FROM UNNEST(test(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM types)))) AS items, 
UNNEST(SPLIT(items)) AS pos
JOIN types ON pos = type_num
GROUP BY items
```

with result

```
Row items   types    
1   1       Cap  
2   2       Jeans    
3   3       Shirt    
4   1,2     Cap,Jeans    
5   1,3     Cap,Shirt    
6   2,3     Jeans,Shirt  
7   1,2,3   Cap,Jeans,Shirt
```

Comment: wow thanks, but what abou the rest like group each payment and its combination?