# BigQuery request, generate combinations and calculate intersection

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table looking like this in BigQuery:

[image]

The first field is `id`, the second field is `url`. 
One line represents someone (an ID) who visited a URL. 
Let's say my URLs are `url1, url2, url3`. I would like to know how many unique IDs visited at least once the following tuples of URLs:

```
(url1, url2)
(url1, url3)
(url2, url3)
(url1, url2, url3)
```

Basically, get the number of ids linked to all combinations of url from the urls list, but only when the number of urls visited is not 0. 
I expect it to give a very big output for a big list of urls. Is there a request I can write in BigQuery that would help with this problem ? 
May be an operator that can generate all combinations for my input ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to implement some specific logic behind, there is no dedicated clause in Bigquery which can address this expectation. For the reference look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229500/how-to-get-combination-of-value-from-single-column), applying UDF to afford combinations of a value for a single column. Is it something that you can be interested in?

Answer (score 4):

> May be an operator that can generate all combinations for my input ?

Yes, you can use [`ML.NGRAMS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-preprocessing-functions#mlngrams) function as in below simplified example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'url1' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'url2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'url2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'url1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'url2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'url3'
)
SELECT tuple FROM (  
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT url) urls
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), UNNEST(ML.NGRAMS(urls, [1,3], ',')) tuple
```

with output

```
Row tuple    
1   url1     
2   url1,url2    
3   url1,url2,url3   
4   url2     
5   url2,url3    
6   url3
```

which you can then use as a input into final calculation