# All possible unique combination of a single column value partitioned by groups

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a table like the following in Google BigQuery. I am trying to get all possible unique combination(all subsets except the null subset) of the `Item` column partitioned on `Group`.

```
Group   Item
1       A
1       B
1       C
2       X
2       Y
2       Z
```

I am looking for an output like the following:

```
Group   Item
1        A
1        B
1        C
1        A,B
1        B,C
1        A,C
1        A,B,C
2        X
2        Y
2        Z
2        X,Y
2        Y,Z
2        X,Z
2        X,Y,Z
```

I have tried to use this accepted answer to incorporate **Group** to no avail:
[How to get combination of value from single column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54229500/how-to-get-combination-of-value-from-single-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION generate_combinations(a ARRAY<STRING>) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  var combine = function(a) {
    var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
      if (n == 0) {
        if (got.length > 0) {
          all[all.length] = got;
        } return;
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
      } return;
    }
    var all = []; for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
      fn(i, a, [], all);
    }
    all.push(a);
    return all;
  } 
  return combine(a)
''';
with your_table as (   
  select 1 as _Group,'A' as Item union all
  select 1, 'B' union all
  select 1, 'C' union all
  select 2, 'X' union all
  select 2, 'Y' union all
  select 2, 'Z' 
)
select _group, item
from (
  select _group, generate_combinations(array_agg(item)) items
  from your_table
  group by _group
), unnest(items) item
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
with _data as
(   
select 1 as _Group,'A' as Item union all
select 1 as _Group,'B' as Item union all
select 1 as _Group,'C' as Item union all
select 2 as _Group,'X' as Item union all
select 2 as _Group,'Y' as Item union all
select 2 as _Group,'Z' as Item 
)
select distinct _Group ,Item  from
(
select  _Group,
        Item
from _data
union all
select  _Group,
        string_agg(Item ,',') over(partition by _Group order by Item )  as item
from _data
union all

select  a._Group ,
        concat(a.item,',',b.item)
        
from _data a left join _data  b on a._group = b._group and a.Item < b.Item 
)
where item is not null
order by _group
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this only works if each group has 3 elements. But group 1 might have 5 elements like A,B,C,D,E and group 2 can have some other number of elements.

Comment: Have you tried with more than 3 elements.?